# Does naming your form fields the same as mysql actually pose any security risk?

Tags: php, mysql, html

Is there any reason why you should or shouldn't name your form fields exactly the same as the HTML fields?

```
<input type="text" name="my_field_1" id="my_field_1" /> --> mysql row my_field_1
```

or

```
<input type="text" name="myField1" id="myField1" /> --> mysql row my_field_1
```

The only thing I can think of are probably naming conventions for HTML vs Mysql (personal preference maybe), as well as slight injection prevention (obviously the field name would have to vary more... but all values should be validated first anyway + the use of real escape string).

Comment: Where is the difference between the 'or'? ;)

Comment: He forgot to format the code. I edited and formatted the code.

Comment: "real escape string"? surely, you mean "parametrized queries".

Comment: alright, so the general consensus is that it doesn't matter, unless of course you just accept any input given in the form (which I would never do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can see this could pose a problem is when the attacker knows the name of a protected column in the same table that is not supposed to be changed through the form, and creates a new input element with that name with the intention of "slipping" the value illegally into the table.

That is something that your program ***must*** filter out anyway on program level, so there's no problem with naming form fields after your actual column names. **You just need to take care to never loop through every available table column or form field**, but be picky about what gets updated.

A secondary, very remote risk is that you are exposing column names in your table. So if you're super-paranoid about security, you may want to give the form fields a name different from their column. But I can't see any real necessity for that.

Comment: while everyone pretty much provided the same answer (which there's nothing wrong with), your post just proves that maybe I'm just a bit paranoid :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're validating then no, but don't limit validation to just what you expect from the form. What if you have a comment table with an owner column and you blindly build a SQL update statement from all the fields in the form, because you know there's no owner field on there? What happens if I use TamperData, a firefox extension which allows me to add data to a request and I add an owner field?

Don't loop through all the fields and accept them, make sure only fields you expect are there and there are no extras!

Answer (score 0):

Actually no one will know that you used the field names instead of custom names (except for some typical column names). How can they now? Maybe you used custom names, maybe not ;)
It makes your code easier to understand if you use the same names and your code will be easier to maintain.

But read the other answers to be aware of the problems that could occur.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed.  No problem.

In fact, if you name the fields the same as the Table fields you can do some cool looping schemes that make updating or inserting into MySQL more automated.

Comment: Looping schemes are a bad idea, as I hope I've expanded upon in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include much code examples, but what I've done in the past marries both of them together.  I usually have an array of fields "expected" that I loop through, grabbing the associated values present in the POST array and the validating.  So it's not a blind loop, no....as that's just a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a security risk as long as your website is 100% safe for SQL injections. So I would rather worry about that fact, than about choosing/using fieldnames.

Answer (score 0):

No, because you should assume that any attacker has access to your entire source code base anyway, so naming them something different would not reduce their capacity to attack you.

The right way to protect an application is to write it correctly, not hide the information someone might need to attack it (they may get it anyway).